# How to read an XML files with nested nodes in pig

Tags: xml, nested, apache-pig, nodes

I want to read an XML file in PIG. The XML file looks like this :

```
<pdv id="10000001" latitude="" .... >
[....]
 <prix id="1" maj="2007-01-01 00:00:00" valeur="12"\>
 <prix id="1" maj="2007-01-01 00:00:01" valeur="15"\>
 <prix id="1" maj="2007-01-02 00:00:00" valeur="56"\>
</pdv>
```

For each pdv (retail outlet), the file has several nodes containing data prices. I want to collect all the prices from each retail outlet like this :

```
10000001,2007-01-01 00:00:00,12
10000001,2007-01-01 00:00:01,15
10000001,2007-01-02 00:00:00,56
```

I tried using this script :

```
REGISTER piggybank.jar

A =  LOAD 'xmls/stations.xml' using  org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('pdv') as (x:chararray);

B = foreach A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x,'<pdv id="[0-9]*" latitude[\\s\\S]*<prix id="1" maj="[^a-z]*" valeur="[0-9]*"/>[\\s\\S]*</pdv>')) AS (id:chararray,prix:float);

dump B;
```

But I only got the first node of each retail outlet. There are too many nested nodes to enumerate them in the script. I tried using Xpath or the XMLStreamingLoader but these syntaxes don't seem to work.

Comment: I am not sure how to get started in this case, but this kind of problem begs to be cut up in even smaller steps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using XPath with @ to fetch all the attributes inside . Below code might help you.

A =  LOAD 'xmls/stations.xml' using  org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('pdv') as (x:chararray);

B = foreach A GENERATE
XPath(x,'pdv/prix/@id') AS id, 
XPath(x,'pdv/prox/@maj') AS maj, 
XPath(x,'pdv/prox/@valeur') AS valeur;

dump B;